# HyperLedger Fabric approve chaincode error:"rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled"

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-orderer

I am creating a Hyperledger fabric network and have created a channel named "mychannel" on VM1 and later I created 3 more VM and joined the channel on vm2 and vm3. Vm4 is my orderer. It is not joined to the channel.

Now I am trying to deploy chaincode to the VM1 first.
I have Org1 for VM1 and Org1 has 2 peers : peer0 and peer1

```
presetup() {
    echo Vendoring Go dependencies ...
    pushd ./../../artifacts/src/github.com/fabcar/go
    GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor
    popd
    echo Finished vendoring Go dependencies
}
# presetup

CHANNEL_NAME="mychannel"
CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE="golang"
VERSION="1"
CC_SRC_PATH="./../../artifacts/src/github.com/fabcar/go"
CC_NAME="fabcar"

packageChaincode() {
    rm -rf ${CC_NAME}.tar.gz
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    peer lifecycle chaincode package ${CC_NAME}.tar.gz \
        --path ${CC_SRC_PATH} --lang ${CC_RUNTIME_LANGUAGE} \
        --label ${CC_NAME}_${VERSION}
    echo "===================== Chaincode is packaged on peer0.org1 ===================== "
}
# packageChaincode

installChaincode() {
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    peer lifecycle chaincode install ${CC_NAME}.tar.gz
    echo "===================== Chaincode is installed on peer0.org1 ===================== "

}

# installChaincode

queryInstalled() {
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled >&log.txt
    cat log.txt
    PACKAGE_ID=$(sed -n "/${CC_NAME}_${VERSION}/{s/^Package ID: //; s/, Label:.*$//; p;}" log.txt)
    echo PackageID is ${PACKAGE_ID}
    echo "===================== Query installed successful on peer0.org1 on channel ===================== "
}

# queryInstalled

approveForMyOrg1() {
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    # set -x
    # Replace localhost with your orderer's vm IP address
    peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg -o localhost:7050 \
        --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls \
        --cafile $ORDERER_CA --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name ${CC_NAME} --version ${VERSION} \
        --init-required --package-id ${PACKAGE_ID} \
        --sequence ${VERSION}
    # set +x

    echo "===================== chaincode approved from org 1 ===================== "

}

# queryInstalled
# approveForMyOrg1

checkCommitReadyness() {
    setGlobalsForPeer0Org1
    peer lifecycle chaincode checkcommitreadiness \
        --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --name ${CC_NAME} --version ${VERSION} \
        --sequence ${VERSION} --output json --init-required
    echo "===================== checking commit readyness from org 1 ===================== "
}

# checkCommitReadyness
```

This is code snippet from my deployChaincode.sh file

I executed each function one by one and got all desired output
but when I am running the approveForMyOrg1 function there is an error

`Error: timed out waiting for txid on all peers`
due to this error I can not proceed ahead and because of this I checked for orderer logs
( Orderer has 3 orderers: orderer , orderer2, orderer3 )

```
2023-06-30 05:40:02.927 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 06d Writing block [10] (Raft index: 14) to ledger channel=mychannel node=1
2023-06-30 05:40:30.904 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 06e Error reading from 10.29.8.25:35778: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2023-06-30 05:40:30.904 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 06f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=10.29.8.25:35778 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=30.119426811s
```

after I saw the log
I tried again and got Raft index: 15 log

```
023-06-30 05:59:51.491 UTC [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] writeBlock -> INFO 070 Writing block [11] (Raft index: 15) to ledger channel=mychannel node=1
2023-06-30 06:00:19.461 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 071 Error reading from 10.29.8.25:50966: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2023-06-30 06:00:19.461 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 072 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=10.29.8.25:50966 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=30.076590275s
```

I can't understand why this time out error is coming and how can I fix it.
I tried increasing timeout time in core.yaml file but it has no effect.

Please help me!